# How to hide nextSibling element in Angular 9

Tags: angular

In my Angular 9 application, I have a part of my sidebar component like this:

```
<h6 (click)=toggle()>
 <span>HOME</span>
 <span>icon</span>
</h6>
<ul class="nav flex-column">
 <li class="nav-item"></li>
</ul>
```

The above code is repeated **multiple times**. By clicking on the h6 tag I would like to hide the ul tag block after the clicked h6 element. There's a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to pass an argument to the toggle call. You can then use the *ngIf directive to hide the list if the condition is met / not met.

```
<h6 (click)="toggle('home')">
 <span>HOME</span>
 <span>icon</span>
</h6>
<ul *ngIf="!menu.home" class="nav flex-column">
 <li class="nav-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your TS file something like this.

```
menu = {
     home: true,
     anotherMenuOption: true
}

toggle(name: string) {
     this.menu[name] = !this.menu[name]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this code is repeated several times, you should thikn of having a model linked to it and use a ngFor on the template.

This way you can link a boolean on your model to hide the ul.

```
  <div *ngFor="let bloc of blocs">
    <h6 (click)=toggle(bloc)>
      <span>{{bloc.Title}}</span>
      <span>{{bloc.icon}}</span>
    </h6>
    <ul class="nav flex-column" *ngIf="bloc.show">
      <li class="nav-item"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

On you TS file, you would have something like :

```
const blocs = [
   {
     show: true,
     title: 'Your text',
     icon: 'your icon'
   }
]

function toggle(bloc): void {
   bloc.show = !bloc.show;
}
```

Hope this helps.